# ST TDA 7265 playing sound problem

Tags: amplifier

I have a problem with TDA7265 amplifier.
I built the single power supply circuit which mentioned in the datasheet (second picture).
I use 20.5V Vs and 2x15W 8ohm speaker for output.

I measured the Mute pin(5) with multimeter and always showed me 14V.
It is enough for play mode. Nothing came out.
Then tried to ground the Mute Pin also.
The drawings are ok in the circuit.
Anybody has an idea what should I try?

Comment: Please link the datasheet, then copy an image of your circuit into the question then show how you implemented it physically.

Comment: https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/tda7265.pdf

Page 2/11              Fig 2: Typical Application Circuit in Single Supply

Comment: So do you have any idea?